# Can Git remind me about or auto-apply a stash when switching back into the corresponding branch?

Tags: git

I often start working on a certain branch (e.g. `new-feature`) and get interrupted by something with a higher priority (e.g. `high-prio`). Most of the time, my changes on `new-feature` are incomplete and therefore I don't want to do a full commit¹, so I `git stash` them before checking out a new `high-prio` branch. This creates a new stash which is associated with `new-feature`:

```
stash@{0}: WIP on new-feature: <sha1 and message of previous commit>
```

Now, I can complete my work on `high-prio`. After I'm done with that I checkout `new-feature` again and (since it has been a while) often forget that there was a stash associated with this branch. This creates problems as I might re-do work I already completed on the stash or I have to merge / rebase those changes later.

Is there a configuration setting which reminds me about the existing stash or, even better, automatically pops the stash back into my working tree after checking out `new-feature` again?

¹ Doing a "WIP"-Commit and later squashing the changes is not a good solution because I want to always keep `origin/new-feature` in sync with my local `new-feature`.

Comment: If your stash is generally clean, you can create alias for `git checkout` as `git stash list && git checkout`

Comment: Have tried the post-checkout git hook? https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/githooks.txt#L160

Comment: If your Git is new enough, you can use `git worktree` to create a temporary work-tree to work on the higher priority item in on the other branch, without displacing your existing work.  I recommend at least 2.6, and there are a bunch of, um, "interesting" bugs in `git worktree` through 2.18 that mean you should not leave an added work-tree around for more than about two weeks, if possible.

Comment: @jayant This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for! Do you want to post that as a complete answer? Otherwise, I'll write a full script (which checks for associated branches) and post that as a answer myself.

Comment: @torek Thanks, but I don't think a worktree is the right solution as I'd want `high-prio` to be commited on its own branch. (And it seems the work-tree would use the currently checkout out one.)

Comment: No, in fact, added work-trees *must* be on some *other* branch (or use a detached HEAD).

Comment: @Nijin22 yes I can do that tonight

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the git [post-checkout](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/githooks.txt#L160) hook like so:

Add the following text to `.git/hooks/post-checkout`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Don't forget to git stash pop the following:"
git stash list
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
branch=$(git branch | sed -n '/\* /s///p')
last_stash_on_branch=$(git stash list --grep="WIP on ${branch}:" | head -1 | cut -d: -f1)
if [[ -n "${last_stash_on_branch}" ]]; then
    git stash pop --index ${last_stash_on_branch}
fi
```

Make it executable

```
chmod +x .git/hooks/post-checkout
```

Now when you checkout any branch your post-checkout script will hopefully remind you check your stashes

Comment: Take it one step further and create global git hooks so this works on every repo https://coderwall.com/p/jp7d5q/create-a-global-git-commit-hook

Answer (score 2):

Here is a trick I use:

In general, prefer to commit over stashing in your case:

```
git checkout -b new-feature

// now instead of stash, commit:

git commit -am "Started implementation"

// now move to high priority branch and do the high priority task
 ... 
// done high priority task

git checkout new-feature 
// now this is the important command: it saves your work in index, removes the commit 
from the branch but all the files are preserved  
git reset --soft HEAD~1

// now to see the outcome, execute
git status
```

Bottom line, `git reset --soft HEAD~1` is your friend here